# Most advantageous starting position in chess

Tags: theory, chess960

What is the most advantageous starting position in chess for White?

All Chess960 positions are known to be *roughly* equal (the standard chess position being one of the fairest starting positions; in other starting positions, White has a larger edge but isn't winning).

Therefore, I'm looking for a position where:

1. White pawns are on the 2nd rank, Black pawns on the 7th rank
2. White pieces are on the 1st rank, and Black pieces are on the 8th rank
3. Both players have a light- and a dark-squared bishop
4. The king is between the rooks.

That looks like Chess960 rules, but with an important difference: the positions do not need to be mirrored. There should be approx. 900k such positions.
Is it possible to construct a position where White is winning or at least significantly better? If so, why, and how did you come up with the solution?

Comment: Might be answered here: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40800/chess960-can-black-profit-by-being-allowed-to-choose-a-custom-setup I wrote that answer before reading this question.

Comment: @Allure would you like to make it an answer? I'll delete my answer then, to give you the credit

Answer (score 1):

@Allure answered the question [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40800/chess960-can-black-profit-by-being-allowed-to-choose-a-custom-setup/) in an answer to a related question.
Thanks :)